# Moment of inertia of a sphere with a spherical cavity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

Ok, consider a solid sphere of radius $R$, from which a spherical cavity of radius $R/2$ is cut out. Now the catch is that the center of the cavity is NOT at the center of the sphere, rather it is at a distance of R/4 from it. So I need to find the remaining portion's Moment of Inertia about the sphere's diameter.

Now I know that we will use parallel axis theorem between axis through center of cavity and through center of sphere, BUT I had first tried to assume that both their axes are NOT parallel, but the same. So how should I attempt this question now? Or should I always take both axes separately and parallel?

Comment: Be careful using the parallel axis theorem with cavities as what is happening is negative density and not negative mass. So you have to transform the MMOI values from mass based to volume & density based before adding or subtracting volumes,

Answer (score 1):

So the MMOI of a sphere or radius in terms of density $\rho$ and volume $V = \tfrac{4}{3} \pi r^3$ is

$$ I_{\rm sphere}  = \tfrac{2}{5} m r^2 = \tfrac{2}{5} \rho V r^2 = \tfrac{8}{15} \rho \pi r^5 $$

And the parallel axis theorem in terms of density volume is

$$ I_{\rm offset} = I_{\rm center} + m d^2=I_{\rm center} + \rho V d^2 = I_{\rm center} + \tfrac{4}{3}  \rho \pi r^3  d^2 $$

Here is a table of how you would build the volume, center of mass and mass moment of inertia.

$$\begin{array}{r|c|c} 
\text{Region} & \text{Radius} & \text{Volume} & \text{CM} & \text{MMOI} \\
\hline
\text{Outside Sphere} & R_1 = R & V_1 = \tfrac{4}{3} \pi R_1^3 & x_1 =0 & I_1=\tfrac{8}{15} \rho \pi R_1^5 \\
\text{Cavity} & R_2 = \tfrac{1}{2} R & V_2 = \tfrac{4}{3} \pi R_2^3 & x_2 = -\tfrac{1}{4}R & I_2=\tfrac{8}{15} \rho \pi R_2^5 \\
\text{Combined} & & V_{\rm tot} = V_1-V_2 & x_{\rm tot} = \tfrac{x_1 V_1 - x_2 V_2}{V_1-V_2} & I_{\rm tot} = I_1 - ( I_2 + \tfrac{4}{3} \rho \pi R_2^3 x_2^2) 
\end{array}$$

In the end you will get MMOI in terms of $\rho$ and $R$, and you need plug in the density of $$ \rho = \frac{m}{V_{\rm tot}} $$ to convert the expression to mass based.

Comment: +1 for that table, was that a lot of work?

Comment: Well, it is a step by step process to evaluate the composite MMOI of solids. Find each volume, center of mass and individual MMOI and combine them appropriately.